# DRF changing field name values of django models with foreign keys

Tags: python, django, orm, django-rest-framework

[I followed suggestion from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920853/aggregate-and-other-annotated-fields-in-django-rest-framework-serializers)
But i need to name one field of query_set to date filed of another object

My models are

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='choice', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text


class ChoiceWithTime(models.Model):
    choiceTime = models.ForeignKey(Choice,related_name='choiceTime', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_date=models.DateField()
```

My view

```
class QuestionChoicesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Choice.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ChoiceDateSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Choice.objects.values('choiceTime__choice_date','choice_text').annotate(
            total_votes=Count('choiceTime__choice_date'),
        )
```

I need to count number of submission in particular dates

I don't know how to name **choiceTime__choice_date** that serializer recognizes field in query set

```
class ChoiceDateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choiceTime__choice_date  = serializers.DateTimeField()
    total_votes = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ('id', 'choice_text','total_votes','choiceTime__choice_date')
```

i receive

```
{
    "choice_text": "ant tower",
    "total_votes": 3,
    "choiceTime__choice_date": "2017-04-20"
}
```

But i want to recieve

```
{
    "choice_text": "ant tower",
    "total_votes": 3,
    "choice_date": "2017-04-20"
}
```

Tried different options with no success. Definitely i am missing the point.
For my purposes it is working, but i want to have well written API.

2 option change time submission model?

```
class ChoiceWithTime(models.Model):
    choiceTime = models.ForeignKey(Choice,related_name='choiceTime', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_date=models.DateField()
    coutner = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Is 2 option considers to be better approach to my particular  problem? Thanks!

Comment: I would appreciate any help on how to serialize related field anyway, for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Count,F
```

If anybody finds this problem and this is easiest answer i came up to.
As it was suggested before passing to serializer change value using model package functions

```
class QuestionChoicesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Choice.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ChoiceDateSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Choice.objects.all().annotate(choice_date=F('choiceTime__choice_date')).values('choice_date','choice_text').annotate(
            total_votes=Count('choiceTime__choice_date'),
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving a json object, which you add its key value.

```
 for vote_detail in data:
   if vote_detail.choiceTime__choice_date:
      vote_detail.choice_date=vote_detail.choiceTime__choice_date
```

then serialize and save, a quick solution.

You could also add to your model the name that you want to call it. That's closer to backend and maybe worth delving into.