# Sum up a field in the queryset in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

models.py

```
class QaCommission(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(PlUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='user_commission')
    ref = models.ForeignKey(PlUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='ref_commission')
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    pct = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    commission = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
```

serializers.py

```
class QaCommissionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = QaCommission
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class QaCommissionList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = QaCommission.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QaCommissionSerializer
```

If we are filtering ref=60 in this view, results show like this:

```
{
"count": 18,
"next": "http://127.0.0.1:8008/api/qacommission/?ref=60&page=2",
"previous": null,
"results": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "price": 20.0,
        "pct": 0.1,
        "commission": 2.0,
        "status": 1,
        "user": 7,
        "ref": 60
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "price": 10.0,
        "pct": 0.1,
        "commission": 1.0,
        "status": 1,
        "user": 7,
        "ref": 60
    },
    ......
    ......
    ......
    {
        "id": 10,
        "price": 15.0,
        "pct": 0.1,
        "commission": 1.5,
        "status": 1,
        "user": 7,
        "ref": 60
    }
]
}
```

I wanna sum up all the "commission" field in the results and attach the sum to the original queryset (maybe next to "count":18), as shown above, there are 18 commission need to be count.

How could I implement this? Need your help, thanks!

Comment: `from django.db.models import Sum
\n
qs = QaCommission.objects.filter().aggregate(commission_sum=Sum('commission'))
sum is stored in qs['commission_sum']`

Comment: Maybe this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920853/aggregate-and-other-annotated-fields-in-django-rest-framework-serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920853/aggregate-and-other-annotated-fields-in-django-rest-framework-serializers) will answer your question

Comment: Adding a class method in model class may help you to sum up of your commision value of queryset result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to override `list()` method of `ModelViewset` as,

```
class QaCommissionList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = QaCommission.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QaCommissionSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
        response.data['sum'] = sum([data.get('commission', 0) for data in response.data['results']])
        return response
```

This answer sum-up the `commision` **from particular page** and displaying it

**UPDATE**

```
from django.db.models import Sum


class QaCommissionList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = QaCommission.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QaCommissionSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if 'ref' in request.GET and request.GET['ref']:
            response.data['sum'] = QaCommission.objects.filter(ref=int(request.GET['ref'])
                                                               ).aggregate(sum=Sum('commission'))['sum']
        return response
```

The abouve answer will return the Whole sum of `commission` column w.r.t the filter (irrespective of the pagination)
Thanks [@bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41316/bruno-desthuilliers) for mentioning such a valid point

Comment: What's the point of having a SQL database if you don't use it ?

Comment: I think he needs, `sum(commission)`  from **current** page

Comment: awesome answer! I need the sum from all pages, but I also benefit from the current page one. Thanks!