# Django - grabbing an additional field from related table

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have the following models:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    SUPERVISOR = 1
    REVIEWER = 2
    VERIFIER = 3
    READ_ONLY = 4
    USER_TYPE = [
        (SUPERVISOR, 'Supervisor'),
        (REVIEWER, 'Reviewer'),
        (VERIFIER, 'Verifier'),
        (READ_ONLY, 'Read Only'),
    ]
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    role = models.IntegerField(
        choices=USER_TYPE,
        default=READ_ONLY
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
```

View:

```
class CommentViewSet(BaseCertViewSet):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CommentSerializer
```

Serializer:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='name'
    )


    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'user',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

**My question**: when I hit the comment API endpoint, I'd like it to return the user **role** from the user model as well. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me (not sure it's the most elegant one, happy to change to a better way of doing that):

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for Comment object"""

    user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='name'
    )

    role = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_role(self, obj):
        user = obj.user_id
        role = User.objects.only('id').get(
            id=user).role
        return role

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('id', 'value', 'text', 'user', 'role',
                  'date_created', 'date_updated')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use a `QuerySet.annotation`:

EDIT: `F` is from `django.db.models` so you have to import that as well.

`queryset = Comment.objects.annotate(user_role=F("user__role"))` in your `CommentViewSet`

EDIT:
In order to get the serializer to recognize the field that you are trying to add to the `QuerySet`, you must also define the field on the serializer like this:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='name'
    )

    # add line below to your code
    user_role = IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        # you have to add it to the list of fields as well
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'user', 'user_role')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

Comment: Thanks. I get: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name 'user_role' is not valid for model 'Comment'.`

Comment: it is two underscores between `user` and `role` - that is how you access properties of related objects, two underscores. in your comment here you only have one

Comment: I should clarify - it is two within the `F('user__role')` that you use the two underscores

Comment: that's just the error returned by django, I do have it exactly as you suggested with double underscore. Is there anything I need to do on the serializer side?

Comment: ah - I see what you are saying now

Comment: this could also be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920853/aggregate-and-other-annotated-fields-in-django-rest-framework-serializers

Comment: @kloster there are two comments in the snippet that I put - make sure you read and see both changes - and I think that it will work for you

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately this solution with edits still yields the same error.

Comment: huh - what versions of django and django-rest-framework are you on? because I actually did have this work for me when I tested it

Comment: django 2.2.7 and drf 3.10.3

Comment: interesting - if you could share your updated code (especially the serializer) I might be able to spot something

Comment: I've updated my view and serializer above with the latest. The queryset expression works when I print the values, however I still get the same error of ```django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name 'user_role' is not valid for model 'Comment'.``` -  I should also mention that I have tested it exactly as you've suggested but got the same result.

Comment: I ended up doing it in a different way. Couldn't make it work with the above suggestion, although the F expression was working on its own. Thanks for taking the time to guide me through this.