# How to serialize annotated field in Django WITHOUT using viewsets?

Tags: python, json, django, ajax, django-rest-framework

I have an annotated field I am trying to include in the response to an AJAX get request. Code:

backend:

```
def ajax_get_tags(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
         data = json.dumps(
             serializers.serialize("json", Tag.objects.annotate(word_count=Count('words')).order_by('-word_count'),
                                   fields=('text', 'is_game')))
    else:
        data = 'fail'
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

frontend:

```
    $.getJSON("{% url 'get_all_tags' %}", function (result) {
        result = JSON.parse(result);
    });
```

How can I send the word count to the frontend? I found [Aggregate (and other annotated) fields in Django Rest Framework serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920853/aggregate-and-other-annotated-fields-in-django-rest-framework-serializers) but I don't want to convert my endpoint to a viewset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have DRF (Django Rest Framework) installed.

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Tag


class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    word_count = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('text', 'is_game', 'word_count')
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from .serializers import TagSerializer

def ajax_get_tags(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        qs = Tag.objects.annotate(word_count=Count('words')).order_by('-word_count')
        serializer = TagSerializer(qs, many=True)
        data = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
    else:
        data = 'fail'
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

frontend: (no need to json parse)

```
    $.getJSON("{% url 'get_all_tags' %}", function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Note that compared to the django core serializer, some information will be lost (pk, etc) but you probably weren't using it anyway